# How to add Featured Image option in wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

recently I am developing a wordpress site. I have 2 questions:

1. I have created a plugin for adding some list data. while adding data, i want to add also the "Featured Image" box (on the right side) in my plugin. How can I do that?
2. How to create a theme option for adding and showing some data at some position of the page?

The plugin code:

```
function losninger_setup_post_types() {

    $losninger_labels =  apply_filters( 'losninger_labels', array(
        'name'                => 'Løsninger',
        'singular_name'       => 'Løsninger',
        'add_new'             => __('Add New', 'løsninger'),
        'add_new_item'        => __('Add New løsninger', 'losninger'),
        'edit_item'           => __('Edit løsninger', 'losninger'),
        'new_item'            => __('New løsninger', 'losninger'),
        'all_items'           => __('All løsninger', 'losninger'),
        'view_item'           => __('View løsninger', 'losninger'),
        'search_items'        => __('Search løsninger', 'losninger'),
        'not_found'           => __('No løsninger found', 'losninger'),
        'not_found_in_trash'  => __('No løsninger found in Trash', 'losninger'),
        'parent_item_colon'   => '',
        'menu_name'           => __('Løsninger', 'losninger'),
        'exclude_from_search' => true
    ));


    $losninger_args = array(
        'labels' => $losninger_labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable'=> true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'has_archive' => false,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'supports' => apply_filters('losninger_supports', array( 'title', 'editor' ) ),
    );
    register_post_type( 'losninger', apply_filters( 'losninger_post_type_args', $losninger_args ) );

}
add_action('init', 'losninger_setup_post_types');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `supports`, add `thumbnail` to the array. See [register_post_type#Arguments](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Arguments).

As for the 2nd question, maybe you're looking for [`add_meta_box`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box).

Comment: Thanks a lot! any idea for the 2nd question?